# NextJs with Custom Server

Tags: next.js

I am trying to use NextJs with custom server. For the same, I have to:

1. Create a next app
2. Prepare it
3. Use the handler to handle the requests.

When I do the above, I get

```
Syntax error: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (5:5):
```

The custom server works nicely for react but throws above in case of Tsx files. I have added babel react preset but it still fails.

When I add .babelrc and do next build it runs successfully but fails when I use .babelrc.js

Also, adding that I get

```
info  - Using external babel configuration from next/next-dekjs/.babelrc.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was fixed by tweaking some configs of next js with a gulp task to automate it w.r.t my server.